# Session in laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.6

```
class ControlController extends Controller
{
    public function anyadirCarrito($id, $quan) {
        $productoCarrito = (object)array(
            'id' =>$id,
            'cantidad' => $quan,
        );
        \Session::push('cart', $productoCarrito);
        return \Session::get('cart');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call this function to store data, but every time I call it, it overwrites the data, I want it to store it next to the other one, but it overwrites it. How can I store it with the other one? And if I give him an id, how can I erase it?

Comment: have you made sure session data is actually being persisted between requests?

Answer (score 2):

The Laravel `Session` operates on a key/value basis. Therefore, when you `push` another item to the key `cart`, you are overwriting the same key to which you pushed the previous value.

If you want to maintain a `cart`, with all the products you've added, you'd first need to retrieve the value, and append the new product. For example:

```
public function addProduct($id, $quantity) {
    // Get cart from session
    $cart = session('cart', []);

    // Increment existing product quantity, or add product to cart
    if (array_key_exists($id, $cart)) {
        $cart[$id]->quantity += $quantity;
    } else {
        $cart[$id] = (object) compact('id', 'quantity');
    }

    // Set cart in session
    session(compact('cart'));

    return $cart;
}

public function removeProduct($id) {
    // Get cart from session
    $cart = session('cart', []);

    // Remove product from cart
    unset($cart[$id]);

    // Set cart in session
    session(compact('cart'));

    return $cart;
}
```

Comment: ... [Sessions - Storing Data - Pushing to Array Session Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#storing-data)